# filter function containing another function in predicate

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I have a question about `filter`. How can I make that my function (`manhattanDistance`) will take each element in list and use it for itself? Can you explain how it can be implemented?

```
func :: [(Int,Int)] ->
        (Int, Int, [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char],
                   [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char]) ->
        [(Int,Int)]
func (x:xs) agent  = filter ((manhattanDistance x agentCoord(agent)) == 1) (x:xs)
```

Comment: That type signature is too long to be easily understood. Do something like `type Agent = (Int, Int, [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char])` and change the type signature to `func :: [(Int, Int)] -> Agent -> [(Int, Int)]`. Even better, make `Agent` a proper `data` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that you weren't using the filter's lambda parameter, and referring to a head of the outer function's list instead. Here's a corrected version:

```
func 
  :: [(Int, Int)] 
  -> (Int, Int, [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char]) 
  -> [(Int, Int)]
func xs agent = 
  filter (\e -> manhattanDistance e (agentCoord agent) == 1) xs
```

By the way, that tuple you have should be normalized to ADTs. It's commonly considered a bad practice to use such huge tuples and by the readability of your function's signature you can kinda see why.